# убрать знак ? из урл

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, url

У меня есть такие ссылки http://mishka-games.xyz/game/?wrecked и http://mishka-games.xyz/game/?tanks, как мне сделать через htaccess или PHP чтобы вопросительный знак исчез?

Comment: Если ссылки у Вас как строки в `PHP` то это замена символа в строке и тогда вопрос имеет отношение к `PHP`. Если же Вам нужно настроить обработку `URL` в веб-сервере через `.htaccess` то это вопрос не имеющий отношения к `PHP`. Опишите точнее Ваш вопрос.

Comment: мне нужно сделать обработку,знак  ? появился после того как я передаю через урл параметр GET (название игры)

Comment: get параметры всегда передаются начиная с ? и между ними, если их больше одного, используются &. Вы конкретно чего добиться хотите? Передавать параметры через get, но убрать знак вопроса из адреса?

Comment: да,сделать так сказать чпу ссылку

Answer (score 0):

что-то вроде этого вам надо, видимо

```
RewriteRule ^game/(.*?)/?$  game.php?name=$1    [L,QSA]
```

Comment: хороши вариант, только слетает стили и подключение к БД)

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта. В первом, Вы можете написать (использовать либу) роутинг, что в действительности, будет лучшим вариантом.

Во втором случае можно пихать реврайты в htaccess. Насчет примера данного другим участником не скажу, но в моем случае работал вот такой реврайт (где то выше правило удаления .php из url):

```
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)$ /game?game_name=$1  [L]
```

В результате URL примет вид:

```
.../game/world-of-tanks
```

если

```
game_name = world-of-tanks
```